# Strange files showing up in some programs

Tags: windows-10, filesystems

Some of my programs, e.g. TextPad (https://www.textpad.com) and Second Copy (http://www.secondcopy.com), show some strange files in some of my folders. 
However, Windows Explorer does NOT show these files. Windows Explorer shows hidden files and system files.

I have attached images showing 
TextPad screen dump (top) 
[image: image1], 
TextPad screen dump (bottom) 
[image: image2] and 
Windows Explorer screen dump 
[image: image3].

What are these files? How to get rid of them?

P.S.: I have changed to a new PC, but the problem did not disappear!

Comment: From the above screenshots, can you give an example of files you don't see, and have you scrolled down on the explorer pane? I bet its just a matter of weird sort order, rather than anything else.

Comment: Examples: Folder 3206618538 and file 607753998.avi are not shown in Windows Explorer, but in TextPad. Yes, the screen dump from Windows Explorer shows all files! By the way, almost all of the strange files have a size equal to a multiplum of 1000 bytes, e.g. 123000 bytes or 4000 bytes.

Comment: When my backup program Second Copy makes a copy on a server of the Desktop folder, the strange files are also copied - and Windows Explorer shows these files when copied to the server! - and shows the size of the files.

Comment: Are you sure the computer is not [infected](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)?

Comment: I am not sure of anything! As I mentioned in my first message, I have changed to a new PC, and the problem did not disappear. And an infection could have been copied from the old to the new PC since I have copied a lot of things. On the other hand we use TRAPS to find virus/infections - and it has found nothing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)